# How do I add a second interface to and existing Web Service?

Tags: web-services

I have an existing web service built using C#. It implements a standardized interface which I cannot change. I would like to add a second interface to the web service but I am unclear on the coding mechanics. For the first interface and have written a class to implement the functions.

Question 1: For the second interface, do I create a new class to implement its functions, or add them to the class defined for the first Interface?

Question 2: What modifications are needed the the configuration file of the service's host program so that it recognizes the new interface?

Comment: Is this an ASMX service, or a WCF service?

Answer (score 0):

If you need them in the same web service, then you could write an interface which extends the compulsory, standardised interface, and then expose that through the web service. It can be consumed by a client expecting either your interface or the simpler one. On the service side, just configure this as implementing your new interface, and you should not break connectivity for a client expecting just the simpler one.